# Is it possible define an XML element in RAML 1.0 which has both text content and attributes?

Tags: xml, attributes, mule, raml

Is it possible define an XML element in RAML which has both text content and attributes?

For example: `<MyExample myAttribute="abc">Here is some text</MyExample>`
From what I can tell, objects cannot have text content, and strings cannot have properties:

As object:

```
MyExample:
  type: object
  properties: 
    myAttribute:
      type: string
      xml:
        attribute: true
```

As string:

```
MyExample:
  type: string
  properties: 
    myAttribute:
      type: string
      xml:
        attribute: true
```

When I try this in a Mule project using `type: object`, I get an error:

```
Element 'MyExample' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only
```

When I try using `type: string`, I get an error

```
Error: Property 'properties' not supported in a RAML 1.0 string node
```